# How do I scrape ::before element in a website using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, screen-scraping

I am trying to extract the information from this website, but I can not extract many of the parts of the page, I want to extract each product, with its respective name, price, image and href

**URL:**
https://www.elcorteingles.es/deportes/search/?s=dunk

This is my code:

```
link = 'https://www.elcorteingles.es/deportes/search/?s=dunk'
response = requests.get(link, headers=headers, timeout=4)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
listadoproductos = soup.find("div", {"class":"card"})
print (listadoproductos)
```

But im getting this result:

```
None
```

Comment: did you import bs4 etc etx?

Comment: Yes! I importes all modules

Answer (score 0):

Problems with site parsing may arise because when you try to request a site, it may consider that this is a bot, so that this does not happen, you need to send `headers` that contain [`user-agent` in the request](https://serpapi.com/blog/how-to-reduce-chance-of-being-blocked-while-web/#user-agent), especially when using `requests` library as it has a [default user agent as `python-requests`](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/589c4547338b592b1fb77c65663d8aa6fbb7e38b/requests/utils.py#L808-L814) and website understand that it's most likely a script that sends a request.

But if you send a browser-like user agent, then the site will assume that you're a user and display information.

To get the required data, you need to get a [`.class` selector](https://serpapi.com/blog/web-scraping-with-css-selectors-using-python/#class_selector) which is responsible for the desired result.

We need to find a selector that is responsible for the "container" in which the price, description and brand are located, in our case it is ".obverse".

Have a look at the [SelectorGadget](https://selectorgadget.com/) Chrome extension to easily pick selectors by clicking on the desired element in your browser which is not always working perfectly, if the page heavily uses JS (in this case we can).

[Check code in online IDE](https://replit.com/@denisskopa/scrape-elcorteingles-products-info#main.py).

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, json, lxml

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
}

data = []

html = requests.get("https://www.elcorteingles.es/search/?s=dunk&v=Deportes", timeout=30)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')

for result in soup.select(".obverse"):
  brand = result.select_one(".product_preview-brand").text.strip(),
  description = result.select_one(".product_preview-desc").text,
  price = result.select_one(".js-preview-pricing").text

  data.append({
      "brand": "".join(brand),
      "description": "".join(description),
      "price": price
  })

print(json.dumps(data, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))
```

Example output:

```json
[
    {
    "brand": "Nobutaka Nishizawa",
    "description": "Slam Dunk. Serie Completa. Episodios 1 a 101 (DVD)",
    "price": "69,99 €"
  },
  {
    "brand": "GEORGE R. R. MARTIN",
    "description": "El caballero errante (Cuentos de Dunk y Egg: El caballero de los Siete Reinos 1)  (Bolsillo) (Tapa blanda)",
    "price": "12,30 € 12,95 € -5%"
  },
  {
    "brand": "GEORGE R. R. MARTIN",
    "description": "La espada leal (Cuentos de Dunk y Egg: El caballero de los Siete Reinos 2)  (Bolsillo) (Tapa blanda)",
    "price": "12,30 € 12,95 € -5%"
  },
  # ...
]
```

There's a [13 ways to scrape any public data from any website](https://serpapi.com/blog/13-ways-to-scrape-any-data-from-any-website/) blog post if you want to know more about website scraping.